# Como utilizar a propriedade UseOptimizedManipulationRouting?

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8-1

Estou tentando utilizar a propriedade `UseOptimizedManipulationRouting` em uma `GridView`, porém, quando tento ajustá-la para False, é retornado que a GridView não possui tal propriedade, apesar [desse artigo da MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/system.windows.frameworkelement.useoptimizedmanipulationrouting%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) dizer o contrário.

Pesquisei bastante tentando encontrar pedaços de código de como implementá-lo, no entanto, tudo o que encontrei foram pessoas relatando que resolveram um problema semelhante ao meu dessa forma.

Alguém sabe como devo proceder para utilizar essa propriedade no Windows Phone 8.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Após pesquisar bastante, descobri que essa propriedade não está presente no `Windows Run Time`, apenas no `Silverlight`. Portanto não é possível utilizar essa propriedade em aplicações Run Time.