# Como travar um pivot quando o evento de Holding for disparado?

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8-1

Estou querendo que quando o evento de `Holding` for disparado, eu consiga bloquear a movimentação do meu `pivot`.

Já tentei utilizar as propriedades `IsEnable` e `IsHitTestVisible`, no entanto eu ainda consigo realizar o *swipe* durante o *holding*. A única propriedade que funcionou foi a `IsLocked`, entretanto, ela "apaga" o cabeçalho, comportamento que não é desejado para a aplicação.

Alguém já passou e conseguiu resolver esse problema?

Answer (score 1):

Dá uma olhada [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18032232/1509954) e [aqui](http://www.imaginativeuniversal.com/blog/post/2010/12/09/WP7-Tip-disabling-the-Pivot-Control-swipe-gesture.aspx)

Nos dois casos é mostrado como desabilitar o "swipe" para o Pivot.
Veja:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Touch.FrameReported += (s, e) =>
    {
        if (e.GetPrimaryTouchPoint(slider1).Action == TouchAction.Up)
        { 
            pivot1.IsHitTestVisible = true; 
        }
    };
}

private void slider1_ManipulationStarted(object sender
    , ManipulationStartedEventArgs e)
{
    pivot1.IsHitTestVisible = false;
}
```

Outra possibilidade é setar a propriedade UseOptimizedManipulationRouting="False".

Comment: eu agradeço a resposta. No caso, eu quero evitar para o Runtime do Windows Phone e a propriedade  `UseOptimizedManipulationRouting` como pode ser visto [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/62805/1333), outro ponto é que isso não resolve para o _ holding_, já que ele desabilita as manipulações, evitando que o `ManipulationStarted` seja "despachado".

Comment: Então, o segundo link (de onde o código acima foi tirado) é para Windows Phone. De qualquer forma, veja outro exemplo de como desabilita os eventos Tap e Holding no WindowsPhone: http://blog.mjfnet.com/2010/07/16/windows-phone-7-detecting-tap-and-hold/